# Restore single stub in sandbox

Tags: javascript, sinon

```
sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

sandbox.stub(db, 'query', () => {
    return Promise.resolve();
});

sandbox.stub(process, 'exit', () => { });
```

`sandbox.restore();` removes all the stubs.

I want to remove ONE stub so I can restub it. For example the `query` stub.

Is this possible? I can't find any information on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can restore single method like this:

```
db.query.restore();
```

for your particular case.

Per sinon documentation:

> var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");
>
> Replaces object.method with a stub function. An exception is thrown if
>   the property is not already a function.
>
> The original function can be restored by calling
>   object.method.restore(); (or stub.restore();).

See http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.6/stubs/